# Input Field Validation with min max values coming from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

as the title says i want to validate (dynamically created) input fields (there could be many). HTML 5 is not supported by the browsers that i have to support :( - so i can't use the build in min max check. 
Lets say i have the following simplified database structure:

id, min-value, max-value, standard value

So when an input field with a specific id is requested by the user a new field is generated in php (get some information from the database) and sent back to the user.

In my opinion i have the following opportunities:

1. i could use some inline js like ...onchange="checkMinMax(minvalue,maxvalue)"
2. append two hiddenfields to this input field with the values and check with global inputValidation function if the input value by an specific input field id matches the min/max clause
3. dont use a database, but define min and max in inputValidation function like:

   ```
   var id = $(inputField).attr('id')
   var val = $(inputField).val()
   switch(id){
   case 1:
   checkMinMax(val ,minvalue, maxvalue);
   break;
   case 2:
   ...
   }
   ```

I hope you can imagine what i am trying to achieve. So i appreciate your comments.

Comment: There is a 4th option: use the data-* attribute i.e. date-min=1 data-max=10 then use JavaScript to get and test these attribute values within the validation routine.

Comment: You should validate client-side for user experience, then revalidate server-side for data integrity.

Comment: I'm not sure if data attributes are supported by IE 8

Comment: @eggyal is a server-side validation necessary even if the user can't see anything without javascript? My project is a webapplication for some statistics and there is no sitereload at any time.

Comment: @user2948467: Yes.  It is trivial for someone to submit to your server whatever they want, irrespective of any client-side validation that you perform.